# What is the reverse of cout.width? (C++)

Tags: c++, iostream, cout

I was trying `std::cout.width(int)` to see what it did, and it pushes the text right to fill a minimum width:

```
TH
```

becomes:

```
        TH
```

to fill a minimum width of 10. I am wondering if A) there is a way to reverse this, have a number of spaces put AFTER the text to fill a minimum width, and B) is there a way to create a maximum width AND a minimum width?

And on a lesser note, is it possible to create a class derived from `cout` or `ostream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Width sets the "column" size for what you are printing next with cout.

```
std::cout << left << "Hello";
```

would print the above as "left" aligned in the column you made.

Different "types" are aligned to certain sides by default.

More info on [this reference page.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/flags/)

Answer (score 1):

> And on a lesser note, is it possible
>   to create a class derived from cout or
>   ostream?

One question at a time is a good idea, but you can't derive from cout because it is an instance, not a class. For details of deriving a new output stream type, read [this book](http://www.angelikalanger.com/iostreams.html).